# Is the collection of continuous functions from R to R a subspace of all functions from R to R over R?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is the collection of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $C^0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$,  a subspace of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$)?

Also, is the collection of differentiable functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $C^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, a subspace of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

(Addition is $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ and multiplication is $(αf)(x) = α · f(x)$)

**My attempt:** The answer to the first question is yes, but I'm not sure about my proof below:

1. $f\equiv0$ is continuous.
2. $f+g\in C^0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ for all $f,g\in C^0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$,
3. $\alpha f \in C^0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ for all $f\in C^0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ and all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$

As for the second question, since each derivative function is also a continuous function, then derivative functions are closed for addition and multiplication. Also, f(x)=0 is a derivative function. Thus, the answer to the second question is yes.

I'd be happy to hear your suggestions or fixes.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @ckefa I think it means that $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space.

Comment: Domain and range of real numbers

Comment: Yes, your arguments are correct; the only issue is how much justification you should give for your claims (1)-(3), which depends on context.

Comment: Note that $C^1(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ is not the set of differentiable functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, but the space of *continuously* differentiable functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. So you also need to show that if $f,g$ have continuous derivatives, then so does $f+g$ and $\alpha f$, and that $0$ has a continuous derivative (though these are all relatively easy to show).